# Deleting all but a few nodes in TensorFlow graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

My use-case of TensorFlow requires me to build a new computation graph for each instance that needs to be processed. This ends up blowing up the memory requirements.

Apart from a few `tf.Variables` that are model parameters, I'd like to delete all other nodes. Other people with similar problems have found  `tf.reset_default_graph()` to be useful, but this would get rid of the model parameters that I need to persist.

What can I use to delete all but these nodes?

Edit:
The instance specific computations actually just means I am adding a lot new operations. I believe these operations are the reason behind the memory issues.

**UPDATE:**
See the recently released tensorflow fold (https://github.com/tensorflow/fold) which allows dynamic construction of computation graphs.

Comment: tf.reset_default_graph

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The tf.graph data-structure is designed to be an *append-only* data-structure. It is therefore not possible to remove or modify existing nodes. Usually this is not a problem, as only the necessary subgraph is processed when running a session.

What you can try is to copy the Variabels of your graph into a new graph and delete the old one. To archive this just run:

```
old_graph = tf.get_default_graph() # Save the old graph for later iteration
new_graph = tf.graph() # Create an empty graph
new_graph.set_default() # Makes the new graph default
```

If you want to iterate over all nodes in the old graph use:

```
for node in old_graph.get_operations():
    if node.type == 'Variable':
       # read value of variable and copy it into new Graph
```

Alternatively you can use:

```
for node in old_graph.get_collection('trainable_variables'):
   # iterates over all trainable Variabels
   # read and create new variable
```

Have also a look at `python/framework/ops.py : 1759` to see more ways on manipulating nodes in graph.

However before you mess around with `tf.Graph` I would strongly recommend to consider whether this is really required. Usually one can try to generalize the computation and use shared variables build a graph, so that each instance you want to process is a subgraph of this graph.

Comment: I just realized that the reason for memory blowing up is the new operations added for each computation. How do I clean these up?