# Prune computation graph in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

A computation graph in tensorflow has some node `input` and some node `output`. `input` represents the input tensor to a neural network, `output` its prediction. Some other subgraph feeds to `input`, some losses (and other computations) follow on `output`. After training is finished, I would like to keep only the (forward) subgraph between `input` and `output`. Is it possible to remove all other ops? [Deleting all but a few nodes in TensorFlow graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37103002/deleting-all-but-a-few-nodes-in-tensorflow-graph) indicates that per-se this is not possible. Maybe through the de-tour of exporting stuff using `tf.train.export_meta_graph`?

Comment: How do you plan to feed `input` when the ops preceding it are removed?

Comment: Well... if you really-really want to, you could custom export only trained variables and then custom load them into a smaller graph... But I don't think it is possible to create a graph and then prune it.

Comment: @Priyatham `sess.run(ouput, feed_dict={input:my_own_preprocessed_stuff})` should do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it is not possible to delete nodes from a `tf.Graph`, TensorFlow includes tools that enable you to prune a lower-level `tf.GraphDef` protocol buffer. The TensorFlow [graph transformation tool](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/99fe61a8a8f3dd41b4e1e4dedfc53b45f67e88a7/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/README.md) includes a transformation pass called [`strip_unused_nodes`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/99fe61a8a8f3dd41b4e1e4dedfc53b45f67e88a7/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/README.md#strip_unused_nodes) that allows you to name set of input nodes and a set of output nodes, and returns a pruned `tf.GraphDef`.